# Argentine slang 're'

Tags: coloquialismos, argentina, prefijos

In Argentina I often hear the word (or prefix?) 're' meaning 'very/real/really'

Some examples are:

> La prueba fue **re** difícil
>
> La película era **re** chota
>
> Estoy **re** bien

- Is 're' an abreviation of another word? (Maybe realmente?)
- Is 're' used anywhere else apart from Argentina?
- Are there any rules regarding the use of 're'?

Comment: `re` = `muy` = `very`

Comment: Archi-requete-recontra-riquísimo.

Comment: It's as common here in Uruguay.

Comment: It's not slang, it's common spanish.

Comment: @Jaime In South America, I have only heard "re" as a synonym of "very" from Argentineans and Uruguayans. Nobody use it in Chile, Peru, Ecuador, Colombia and Venezuela, so I don't think it is *common* Spanish.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista So, you have been there and therefore know that? I hear it in telenovelas all the time, including for Colombia. I could not provide a list, though. Mexico, yes, Spain yes.

Comment: @Lambie I've been in those countries for 10 months while backpacking in South America and have never heard "re". Maybe it's common in specific groups of people I haven't met and/or areas I haven't gone. I have heard it often in Argentina and Uruguay, though.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Did you read what Diego said below??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a prefix. This is what RAE says:

> re-. (Del lat. re-).
>
> 1. pref. Significa 'repetición'. *Reconstruir.*
> 2. pref. Significa 'movimiento hacia atrás'. *Refluir.*
> 3. **pref. Denota 'intensificación'. *Recargar.***
> 4. pref. Indica 'oposición' o 'resistencia'. *Rechazar. Repugnar.* Significa 'negación' o 'inversión del significado simple'. *Reprobar.*
>    Con adjetivos o adverbios, puede reforzarse el valor de
>    intensificación añadiendo a re- las sílabas -te o -quete. *Retebueno.*
>    *Requetebién.*

In the uses you provide, it's the third meaning, where it's used to intensify the adjective.

I think in Spain "requete-" is more used than "re-", at least in some cases. In fact, if I hear someone say *rebueno* I automatically think they're from America.

Comment: As a sidenote, sometimes in Argentina, `requete-` is used as a more emphatic version of `re-`. In the popular reasoning, it makes sense that it is bigger since it includes the word. :P

Answer (score 5):

> Are there any rules regarding the use of 're'?

First, as said in other answer, it's a prefix, not a word.

It should be used only colloquially, in casual speak. It's emphatic and slightly childish.  In general, you'll prefer 'muy'.

Comment: I don't think it is childish in Argentina. I have met a lot of Argentineans in their 20s which use it.

Answer (score 4):

This is very common in Mexico as well it is considered very improper but it is used very often in social situations to **re**enforce and **re**mark a word. The most common is

> El examen fue redifícil

to say it was not just hard, but *really* rehard.

Comment: ¿Absurdo? Qué tiene de absurdo un intensificador, cuando existen precisamente para eso, para intensificar.

Comment: Considered improper? Improper in English means indecent or behaviorally bad. It's just colloquial.

Answer (score 2):

> Is 're' an abbreviation of another word? (Maybe realmente?)

Sometimes it's used as *recontra*, especially if used as stand alone word. Not sure of the etymology, my first thought would be [bidding in contract bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contract_bridge#Auction_or_bidding) where one of translation of double and redouble is *contra* and *recontra*. But that just my impression, could be totally wrong.

A derivative of *re-* is *requete-* sometimes used to indicate something even more intense, than *re-*.

> Is 're' used anywhere else apart from Argentina?

Yes, it's very typical in Mexico,it is used in other Latin-American countries (eg. in Peru).

Comment: In Perú we usually use `recontra`, `re` is really uncommon

Comment: I have never heard "re" used as "very" in Peru.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista "RCSM" is one clear example very popular in Peru.

Comment: @vartec Thanks for the example, but is "re" ever used outside fixed expressions such as CSM in Peru? In Argentina, it is as usual as "muy", so you hear in everyday dialogue: recopado, rehermoso, retranquilo, etc. And if anyone wondered what RCSM means: http://diccionariolibre.com/definicion/RCSM/3724

Comment: @AlanEvangelista there are few more like that. It's not used for _everything_ like in Argentina, but it is used.

Answer (score 2):

The expression "re" is very common in my country (Colombia) and it has the same meaning you implied, basically to augment the effect of something.

Its usage is more common among young people. Older people do not use it as much, or sound kind of off when they they say it.

I do not think it is an abbreviation of another word. I believe it works as an adverb.

I can attest it is pretty common in Colombia in all generations up to the gen-x, and, from previous interactions with other people, I know for a fact it is widely used in Venezuela too. It most likely is often used in Chile and Mexico as well.

The only rule I can think of regarding its usage is that it almost always precedes an adjective. I.e. He is very TALL --> He is re TALL; that said, it can also precede verbs, but that usage is less common. i.e "La re cagué" (I screwed up BIG TIME), highly informal usage, mainly among friends.

By the way, it is highly informal. Do not use it in formal conversation. In that case replace "re" with "muy", "bastante" or "demasiado".

Comment: Yes, in all the telenovelas. Which is where I heard it a lot, as in Reina del Flow. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not a native speaker but...

Some other answers seem to be confusing `re-` as a prefix and `re` as a word, a slang equivalent of 'muy' (= very). As an example in context (from Gaturro, referring to a smartphone)

> ¡¡Está genial, re cool, re moderno!!

Comment: The distinction between a prepositioned adjective and a prefix is almost purely orthographical as evidenced with the changes to *ex-* in the 2010 Orthography. The standard way to write what you have would be *recool* and *remoderno*, just as with other similar prefixed intensifiers: *requetemoderno* and *permoderno*. *Re* as a single word refers to the musical note D

Answer (score 1):

Soy de argentina y sí, se usa solo acá. Como dijieron anteriormente, se utiliza para intensificar algo (verbos y adjetivos, sobre todo)
Y no, no hay reglas concretas de gramatica porque no creo que se una palabra "oficial"

```
Te lo comiste a Juan? Sí, me lo re comí. 
Messi es re buen jugador. 
¡Anoche la cena estuvo re linda!
Ese pibe esta re bueno
Aquella montaña rusa es re divertida
Etc
```

Espero que te haya servido!

Answer (score 1):

Estoy seguro de que esta partícula `re`  (p.ej., "recontar") se oye sólo en la Argentina. Hasta ahora no se puede encontrar de dónde lo sacaron los Argentinos. `Re` significa "muy" y el también sufijo "-ísimo", igualmente tiene el significado de "gran", "grande", "súper"... En vez de decir : *Buenísimo*, decimos : *Rebueno*.

A veces, si queremos ir más allá de la intensificación, el esquema resultará así: *Rebuenísimo* o *Recontrabuenísimo*.

Cabe notar que "recontra" se usa frente a una palabra que empieza con la consonante R.

No se dice "rerápido" pero sí "recontrarápido".

Lo empleamos con un verbo casi del mismo modo que si fuera un adjetivo o sustantivo, sólo en ese caso él tomará el significado intensificado del verbo.

ej:

> estoy refeliz esta noche.
>
> tengo una relija ( un gran Hambre)
>
> este bondi viaja recontra rápido
>
> esta frutilla, me la recomí anoche. ==== en este caso, significa que : anoche yo me comí la frutilla con muchas ganas, y me la disfruté mucho.
>
> reviajar = viajar mucho y con muchas ganas...