# ¿Cuál es el origen del prefijo "requete-"?

Tags: etimología, prefijos

Con frecuencia se usa *requete-* para enfatizar:

> - La comida estaba **requetebuena**, estuvimos untando pan hasta que
>   no quedó ni rastro.
>
> - ¡Pásalo **requetebién** en tus vacaciones!

El DRAE lo describe así:

> **[requete-](http://dle.rae.es/?id=W6oHLV2)**
>
> 1. pref. Denota 'intensificación'. *Requetefamoso.*

Y parece que es parecido al [re- usado en Argentina](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1357/1674) (y en otras regiones).

Pero me parece un prefijo muy curioso, máxime cuando tiene el mismo nombre (salvo la tilde) de una organización militar ([requetés](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requet%C3%A9)).

¿Alguien sabe cuál es su origen? ¿Es siempre equivalente a `re-`?

Comment: En las comedias de Chespirito dicen recontra(-chanfle) en lugar de requete. Eso sugiere que el origen de requete, o al menos su popularización, es posterior a Chespirito.

Comment: Según el Diccionario de Mejicanismos de Feliz Ramos y Duarte (Ed 1898)

**Requetebién** (Yuc), adj. Bonísimo, muy bien.

Comment: @SantiagoTórtora - *recontra* me hace pensar en el instrumento musical *contrafagot*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

En la web de la RAE se puede consultar el [mapa de diccionarios históricos](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/mapa-de-diccionarios) por lemas. Si consultas ahí el término, verás que existe tanto en el diccionario de 2001 como en el de 1992, pero no antes (el siguiente ya es de 1925). En estos dos diccionarios, si buscas *requete-* simplemente te redirige a la definición de *re-*, que entre otras cosas dice lo siguiente:

> Con adjetivos o adverbios, puede reforzarse el valor de intensificación añadiendo a re- las sílabas **-te** o **-quete**. ***Rete***bueno. **Requete**bién.

Con esta definición a mí se me antoja que el proceso tuvo más que ver con un caso de "a ver quién cuenta hasta más alto":

> -Esto está bueno.
>
> -No, está rebueno.
>
> -Yo aún diría más, está retebueno.
>
> -No sabéis nada, está requetebueno.

Que traducido al español de hoy en día sería como decir *esto está súper mega ultra hiper bueno* y a ver a quién se le ocurren más prefijos.

---

Además, creo que [este artículo](http://www.degruyter.com/dg/viewarticle.fullcontentlink:pdfeventlink/$002fj$002froma.2010.60.issue-1$002f9783110223095.2.239$002f9783110223095.2.239.pdf?format=INT&t:ac=j$002froma.2010.60.issue-1$002f9783110223095.2.239$002f9783110223095.2.239.xml) de Inmaculada García Jiménez, escrito en febrero de 2010 y que forma parte del libro *Word-Formation: An International Handbook of the Languages of Europe*, te va a resultar de gran interés (demasiado largo y completo como para citarlo, pero creo que resolverá todas tus dudas). SPOILER: El primer caso documentado de *rete-* es de 1859 por Fernán Caballero, y el primero caso documentado de *requete-* es de 1873 por Benito Pérez Galdós.

---

Por último, he trasladado tu consulta a la RAE, para ver si existe alguna correlación entre el prefijo y los requetés.

Esta es su respuesta, que incluye una referencia a *requete-* incluso anterior a la del artículo mencionado:

> El prefijo *requete-* se documenta a ambos lados del Atlántico al menos desde el último tercio del siglo XIX. Valgan unos testimonios de uso:
>
> **1866** Vergara y Vergara, José María. *Las tres tazas [Museo de cuadros de costumbres]* (COLOMBIA).
>
> *-¿Que el café está muy cargado?*
>
> *-Está requetecargado.*
>
> **1879** Pérez Galdós, Benito. *Los Apostólicos* (ESPAÑA).
>
> *Iremos a la casa de D. Francisco Bringas, de cuyos balcones se ha de ver muy requetebién toda la comitiva.*

Comment: Qué respuesta tan fantástica: elaborada, perseguida y finalmente redonda. Es curioso que el _re-_ ahora en España no se use en absoluto y se identifique con el hablar de Argentina.

Comment: Además, el proceso de "a ver quién cuenta hasta más alto" me recuerda los nombres de los emperadores romanos, en que cada uno se añadía un Augusto, Magno, etc para dar más pomposidad a su nombre :)

Answer (score 4):

En resumen, el [estudio](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&ved=0ahUKEwju7JmSzZ7NAhXJDpAKHf8LCW8QFghIMAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.degruyter.com%2Fdg%2Fviewarticle.fullcontentlink%3Apdfeventlink%2F%24002fj%24002froma.2010.60.issue-1%24002f9783110223095.2.239%24002f9783110223095.2.239.pdf%3Fformat%3DINT%26t%3Aac%3Dj%24002froma.2010.60.issue-1%24002f9783110223095.2.239%24002f9783110223095.2.239.xml&usg=AFQjCNGQ-9-hEj1HY7-LI7vUe292giLznA&sig2=FXm_LPMlsgAhjFutSM9nzw&cad=rja) citado en la pregunta aceptada indica tres teorías acerca del origen de *requete*.

En los tres casos se habla de una **metátesis**, es decir, hay un cambio en la posición de los sonidos de una palabra.

**1.** Se habría originado a partir de la interjección *reteque*, que se usa estribillos de un estilo africano llamado *zarambeque*, muy popular en España desde el siglo XVII. Por ejemplo en *Volatines y mojiganga*:

```
Pus qui vengo á rienda suelta
por sólo curar su vuelta
con vueltas del zarambeque,
teque, reteque, teque, reteque.
```

En un entremés de Antonio de Solis llamado *El niño caballero*, en el que se baila y canta zambeques, aparecen dos personajes llamados Teque y Reteque, que son gigantes, y de ahí proviene una expresión aparentemente conocida en España: *A teque reteque*, que significa "repleto". De este gigante Reteque vendrían los prefijos rete- y requete-.

**2.** A partir de la antigua forma *quetarré*, siguiendo aproximadamente la siguiente vía:

> ¡qué tan reviejo!  >  quetarré viejo  > requete viejo

**3.** A partir del prefijo *tatara* (el de tatarabuelo), intensificado con un *re-*, de la siguiente forma:

> tatara feo  > retata feo  > recata feo > requete feo

Como sea, es de origen andaluz y, junto a *rete*, es el prefijo de aparición más reciente en la lengua española.