# ¿Existe algún orden para los elementos compositivos que aumentan al adjetivo al que preceden?

Tags: adjetivos, prefijos, superlativos

En el idioma español tenemos una amplia variedad de elementos compositivos que se pueden anteponer a los adjetivos para hacerlos superlativos:

- *[Super-](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YidtEBo)*: Significa 'en grado sumo'.
- *[Hiper-](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KQQdgjV)*: Significa 'exceso' o 'grado superior al normal'.
- *[Ultra-](http://dle.rae.es/?id=b2QZCEO)*: Significa 'en grado extremo'.
- *[Mega-](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OmkR9wz)*: Significa 'grande'.

No sé si existirá algún otro elemento compositivo similar (algunas personas empiezan a usar ya *[über-](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/%C3%BCber-)*, como préstamo de otros idiomas y que significa "ejemplo superlativo de su tipo o clase"). Estos elementos compositivos se pueden combinar en el habla coloquial, y así decir que algo es "hipermegabueno", y entonces es cuando se empieza con la [coña](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AiDpZIq) de si algo "hipermegabueno" es mejor o peor que algo "superultrabueno".

Así que vamos a trasladar esta broma a una pregunta real: tomando esta lista de prefijos y, si es necesario, añadiendo los que faltan, ¿existe algún orden más o menos oficial para los grados de estos elementos compositivos?

Por las definiciones, se podría decir que de menos a más van "mega", "hiper", "super" y finalmente "ultra", aunque es debatible si "en grado sumo" es más o menos que "en grado extremo".

Otros elementos compositivos que han ido apareciendo en comentarios:

- *[Archi-](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3SE1R6t)*: Con adjetivos, se emplea en lenguaje coloquial y significa 'muy'.
- *[Re-](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VFxyLmQ)*, *[rete-](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WGirRmb)* y *[requete-](http://dle.rae.es/?id=W6oHLV2)*: Denotan 'intensificación'. <sub>(Relacionada: [¿Cuál es el origen del prefijo "requete-"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17038/12637))</sub>

Comment: No sé, un hipermercado suele ser mayor que un supermercado. ¿Entrarían en esa escala otros prefijos como archi, re, requete, recontra?

Comment: Según la definición de "sumo" (que no tiene superior) **Super** sería el máximo pero en la realidad _super_ es el primero que usamos y de ahí comenzamos a aumentarle con los otros.

Comment: @angus sí, parte del propósito de la pregunta es completar la lista con los prefijos que se me hayan olvidado. Y sí que es cierto que un hipermercado suele ser más grande, cosa curiosa si nos ceñimos a las definiciones de la RAE. Puede ser una buena pregunta para ellos.

Comment: Por cierto, veo que la RAE los llama [_elementos compositivos prefijo_](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/terminos-linguisticos). Mirando la entrada [Escritura de prefijos y elementos compositivos](http://es.lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Usuario_Blog:Ling%C3%BCista/Escritura_de_prefijos_y_elementos_compositivos) no me parece que haya ninguno más que los que mencionas.

Comment: A los *re-* se les puede sumar (en `es-ar`) *recontra-* y *remil-* (y recursivamente, *requete-recontra-*, *[recontra-remil-](https://twitter.com/norabromero1/status/838907951763050497)*, etc.).

Comment: Tangencialmente, en [esta noticia](http://deportes.elpais.com/deportes/2017/03/10/actualidad/1489133862_808776.html) diferencian entre _ultra_ y _súper_.

Answer (score 3):

Teniendo en cuenta la fuente que cito ([*Los prefijos intensivos del español: caracterización morfo-semántica*, Josefa Martín García, 1998.](https://rua.ua.es/dspace/bitstream/10045/6331/1/ELUA_12_07.pdf)), entiendo que para algunos sí existe un orden determinado, mientras que para otros no porque aplica un prefijo u otro de acuerdo a la situación.

En la fuente se menciona que algunos prefijos aumentativos se encuentran en una escala de gradación. Por ejemplo super-hiper-mega-macro:
ejemplo: **mercado-supermercado-hipermercado-megamercado-macromercado**.

Con respecto al prefijo "re" se menciona que su uso se da únicamente para intensificar un verbo (rebuscar), o un adjetivo (rebarato), siendo poco recomendado su uso en adverbios (rebien) y nombres (retonto). Se menciona también que su uso es más bien coloquial, que se usa más que todo en el español de Hispanoamérica y que es más usado el similar "super".

Sobre archi y ultra se habla sobre la preferencia de uno u otro dependiendo de si el lenguaje es coloquial o culto:

> La diferencia entre los dos prefijos superlativos del español reside en los
>   distintos ámbitos en que se utilizan. Así, ARCHI- se inscribe dentro de un registro
>   más coloquial y ULTRA- pertenece, por el contrario, a un registro más culto dentro
>   de los lenguajes especializados de la política, de la ciencia o del periodismo.

Imagino que otros usos vienen dados por la costumbre también, por ejemplo es normal escuchar que el día está super bonito, pero no creo que nadie diga que está hiper bonito.