# La cara y la cruz de las monedas

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, solicitud-de-término, españa

Cuando de pequeño teníamos que decidir pelota o campo tirábamos una moneda y lo decidíamos [a cara o cruz](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7NOG7x2#EySq20F). Por aquel entonces las monedas eran así:

[image]

Como se ve, por un lado estaba la cara (de aquel al que le tocara regir el país en ese momento), y por otro la cruz, que por eliminación era donde estaba el escudo con el valor de la moneda. La definición de *cruz* parece apoyar esto:

> **[cruz](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BOPN2zP)**
>
> 6. f. Por oposición a las caras de las monedas, reverso en el que solían figurar los escudos de armas, generalmente divididos en cruz.

Luego parece que sí, la cara donde estaba el escudo es la cruz, y coincidía con la cara donde estaba el valor de la moneda. La definición de *cara* es la que me ha sorprendido. Es sinónima de *anverso* así que pongo esa definición:

> **[anverso](http://dle.rae.es/?id=30HLHxR)**
>
> 1. m. En las monedas y medallas, haz que se considera principal por llevar el busto de una persona o por otro motivo.

Me sorprendió que la cara principal de una moneda fuese donde estaba la efigie. Yo habría dicho tranquilamente que la cara principal es donde está el valor de la misma. Y de hecho, teniendo en cuenta que en las actuales monedas de euro en muchas de ellas no hay una cara con una "cara" (es decir, la cara de una persona), hoy día parece que es normal que cuando se juega algo a "cara o cruz" hay que acordar previamente cuál es la cara y cuál es la cruz.

[image]

De hecho, hay algunas monedas que literalmente tienen un dibujo de una cruz en donde tradicionalmente estaba la cara. Así pues, me surgen algunas dudas:

- ¿Existe alguna denominación alternativa para las caras de la moneda que no dé lugar a confusión? Por ejemplo, en el ámbito de la numismática que estarán más acostumbrados a tratar con monedas de todo el mundo; o tal vez alguna usada en Hispanoamérica que desconozca.
- Definiciones de la RAE aparte, en la calle ¿qué se entiende como "cara" o "cruz"? Tengo un amigo que afirma que la cara de la moneda es donde está el valor, y la cruz es "lo de atrás". A fin de cuentas, para la gente de a pie lo importante de una moneda (lo "principal" a efectos prácticos) es saber cuánto vale.

Comment: En Chile se llama Cara o Sello. No alcanzamos a tener cara/cruz (a menos que las monedas españolas de 1500 sirvan para la idea).
Además se relaciona con que las monedas chilenas acostumbran a llevar efigie o dibujo y al otro lado el monto. Por lo tanto, la cara es la efigie/dibujo y el sello el que le da valor a la moneda.

Comment: Otra cosa curiosa es que cada uno de los lados de una moneda también se llama cara, así que tenemos una cara cara y una cara cruz, un lío todo.

Comment: As so often this site has made me reflect on my own language. One of its unintended happy features. We call them heads and tails but, as far as I know, they never have had a picture of a tail on them. Tail is just the normal opposite of head.

Comment: @mdewey and in many cases they don't have a "head" in them neither...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- *¿Existe alguna denominación alternativa para las caras de la moneda que no dé lugar a confusión?*

Los términos habituales para referirse a las caras de una moneda son: [cara](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7NOG7x2), [anverso](http://dle.rae.es/?id=30HLHxR), [faz](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HhHgjQW#7hvT3jg) o [haz](http://dle.rae.es/?id=K3eNwLc#8iPwVBS) (para el lado con el motivo principal); y [cruz](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BOPN2zP#K07kIKE), [reverso](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WOCkWYg#DsnM7jN) o [envés](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FsOGZF4) (para el lado con el motivo secundario).

Los más técnicos son *anverso* y *reverso*; los que menos llevan a confusión suelen ser *cara* y *cruz*, siempre que la moneda muestre físicamente una cara o una cruz que tomar como referencia. *Faz* es sinónimo de cara, y *haz* y *envés* se toman por analogía con las caras de la hoja de una planta (aunque *haz* también es sinónimo de cara y, como tal, a veces se usa de forma genérica para referirse a cualquiera de las dos caras de la moneda, como puede verse en algunas de las definiciones enlazadas).

Al final, como todo depende de lo que consideremos "principal", en cierto modo es algo subjetivo.

- *Definiciones de la RAE aparte, en la calle ¿qué se entiende como "cara" o "cruz"? Tengo un amigo que afirma que la cara de la moneda es donde está el valor, y la cruz es "lo de atrás". A fin de cuentas, para la gente de a pie lo importante de una moneda (lo "principal" a efectos prácticos) es saber cuánto vale.*

Aquí solo puedo darte una respuesta subjetiva. Para mí:

- Siempre que una moneda lleve una cara o efigie en uno de sus lados, ésa es la *cara*.
- En el caso de las monedas de euro, para mí la cara es la que diferencia un país de otro, pues en las de mayor valor es la que muestra la cara del Rey (o [los Reyes](https://eurocoinland.wordpress.com/2014/10/22/2e-conmemorativos-espana-2-2014-proclamacion-de-s-m-el-rey-felipe-vi/)) y no voy a estar cambiando de criterio según la moneda sea de 2 euros o de 50 céntimos.
- En general, para cualquier moneda que tenga un dibujo mínimamente elaborado en un lado, y el [valor facial](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bJeLxWG#AIqto56) en el otro lado, la *cara* es la del dibujo, y la *cruz* la del valor. Este criterio es el que se suele seguir en numismática, por cierto (aunque resulte algo irónico que la *cruz* sea la que tiene el valor *facial* :D).
- Para [monedas hiper mega simples](https://www.todocoleccion.net/monedas-locales/ficha-mallorca-valor-20-letras-gts-anverso-reverso-jc-diametro-30-mm-clasificar~x25166354), lo cierto es que no hay una regla definida. Se llama *cara* al lado que más importante nos parezca, y ya está.
- En última instancia, si vamos a usar la moneda para decidir *a cara o cruz*, acordamos cuál es la cara antes de lanzarla :)

Comment: [¿"Hiper mega" es más que "super ultra" o menos?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20022/12637)