# ¿Qué significa la palabra "retebién"?

Tags: significado, palabras-raras, prefijos

No he podido encontrar la significación de la palabra "retebién".

Estoy leyendo el libro *Los Detectives Salvajes*. Ahí leí esta frase:

> Nosotros también somos artistas, lo que pasa es que lo disimulamos **retebién**, ¿no?

¿Podría alguien explicarme esa palabra por favor?

Comment: Yo diría que según el contexto que planteas, "retebién" significa que disimulan muy bien.

Comment: ¿Han oído decir "requetebien"?  Lo he oído en el habla mexicano mucho.  Creo que es similar en su sentido.

Comment: [Relacionada](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17038/12637).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [¿Cuál es el origen del prefijo "requete-"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/cu%c3%a1l-es-el-origen-del-prefijo-requete)

Comment: @aparente001 I don't think it's a duplicate. The other question was about the etymology of the "requete-" prefix, so even though the answers indicate that "rete-" is another form for the same prefix, its meaning is only discussed tangencially. This question asks specifically for its meaning so I think it deserves to be left open.

Comment: También se puede encontrar la expresión retebien en los episodios nacionales de Benito Pérez Galdós en “La Corte de Carlos IV”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> #### [rete-](https://dle.rae.es/?id=WGirRmb)
>
> 1. `pref.` Denota 'intensificación'. *Retebueno.*

Más información: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/rete-retebien-retebonito.2219794/

Answer (score 6):

El prefijo **re, rete o requete**, se utiliza en algunos adjetivos calificativos. Su significado es para expresar una mayor expresión al adjetivo.

Por ejemplo:

Bueno - **rebueno** o **retebueno** - significa que algo esta muy bueno.
Bien - **rebien** o **retebien** - significa que algo esta muy bien.
Sabroso - **resabroso** o **retesabroso** - significa que algo esta muy sabroso.

Espero te sirva mi explicación.

Comment: Sabia lo del re, pero no del rete or requete. Lo he oído en telenovelas mexicanas en contextos negativos....¿tienes algunos ejemplos? No recuerdo ningun ejemplo ahora.